# Generic InputCell for gwt Column (Change Cell-type or know Property's Cell-type before creating Column-constructor)

Tags: java, gwt, input, gwt-celltable

In our existing GWT project we have a table with multiple cells. We use `com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.Column.Column` for the columns of this table. Here is our current code:

```
private void addColumns() {
    // label column
    final Column<Property, String> labelColumn = new Column<Property, String>(new TextCell()) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(final Property object) {
            return object.getPdf().getName();
        }
    };

    this.datagrid.addColumn(labelColumn, "Label");
    this.datagrid.setColumnWidth(labelColumn, 40, Unit.PX);

    // value column
    final Column<Property, String> valueColumn = new Column<Property, String>(new TextInputCell()) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(final Property object) {
            return object.getValue();
        }
    };
    valueColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Property, String>() {
        @Override
        public void update(final int index, final Property object, final String value) {
            final Property existingObject = containsObject(object);
            if (existingObject != null) {
                existingObject.setValue(value);
            } else {
                // else add the object to the "editedFields" list
                object.setValue(value);
                UserDefinedFieldsValuesDiv.this.editedProperties.add(object);
            }
        }
    });
    this.datagrid.addColumn(valueColumn, "Waarde");
    this.datagrid.setColumnWidth(valueColumn, 40, Unit.PX);
}
```

This will generate a table like this:
[image]

Currently everything is a `TextInputCell`, but I want to change this based on the type of the column. So if it's a date, I want a DatePickerCell, etc.

In the following segment of the code:

```
// value column
final Column<Property, String> valueColumn = new Column<Property, String>(new TextInputCell()) {
    @Override
    public String getValue(final Property object) {
        return object.getValue();
    }
};
```

It gives a `new TextInputCell()` as parameter, but only inside this column I can retrieve the type by using `object.getType().name().equals(Type.DATE.name())`. I've looked in the source-code of the `Column`, but there is only a `getCell` method, no `setCell`. Is there a way to change the cell-type of a Column, OR a way to know beforehand what type the cell is (which I can retrieve from the `Property`)?

PS: This is my first day using GWT, so I might not be very familiar with some things yet.

---

EDIT:

So what I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
// value column
AbstractCell cell = new TextInputCell();
Property propertyISomehowRetrieved = ...;
if (propertyISomehowRetrieved.getType().name().equals(Type.DATE.name())){
    cell = new DatePickerCell();
} else if(propertyISomehowRetrieved.getType().name().equals(Type.NUMERIC.name())){
    cell = new NumberCell();
} else if(propertyISomehowRetrieved.getType().name().equals(Type.BOOLEAN.name())){
    cell = new CheckboxCell();
}
final Column<Property, String> valueColumn = new Column<Property, String>(cell) {
    @Override
    public String getValue(final Property object) {
        return object.getValue();
    }
};
```

But how do I retrieve this property?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Currently every input cell is a `TextInputCell` (given to the Column-constructor). Instead, I want to use a `DatePickerCell` when the data-type is `Type.DATE` and such. My problem however is that the property to determine the data-type is only retrievable after I instantiated the Column (using `property.getType()`), so I can't change the `cell-type` of the Column anymore. (I've also made an edit to my question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each column may use only one cell. This is why the cell type is passed into the constructor and cannot be changed. You cannot use different cells for different rows, as you show in your example.

When you build a DataGrid with multiple columns, you can add different columns based on the properties of an object, which this DataGrid is going to display. For example, if your object has two properties "Date" and "Title", you can add two columns with DatePickerCell and TextInputCell. Since this is *your* object, you know the types of properties before you build the DataGrid, so you can add the correct columns and choose the desired cell type when you build it.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the answer. This is rather unfortunate however for what we want to achieve.. Is there a different way in GWT to make a table with a row like: "Label1 [TextInputField]"; "Label2 [DatePickerInputField]"; "Label3 [NumericInputField]"; etc.? Or should something different than a table be used for this?

Comment: The idea of a CellTable or DataGrid is that each column has only one type of data, and each row represents an object of the same type. This allows features like sorting the table by a selected column, selection handler, etc. If each row represents a different object, there is no point in using a DataGrid. Instead, you can build your own widget (e.g. "RowWidget") to represent each row, and add these RowWidgets to any container (e.g. FlowPanel). This RowWidget may contain a Label and another Widget, which can be TextBox, DateBox, etc.

Comment: Sounds indeed pretty obvious. Thanks for making it a bit clearer for me. Like I said, I've only started with GWT today, so I don't know the possibilities and limitations yet, but how you've explained it indeed makes sense (having the same column for sorting purposes / filter purposes). I will rewrite the existing code to remove the table and use label-inputfield rows. I kinda dislike tables anyway for these kind of purposes, mainly in HTML where you can use divs, but also in these kind of situations in other programming languages. Thanks.

Comment: The beauty of GWT is that it's compiled, and all unused methods are not included in the final code. Thus, even though the DataGrid widget itself is quite heavy, the resulting code is not even if you use only a small portion of its functionality. Moreover, there is little or no benefit to remove one instance of a widget, if there are other instances used elsewhere in an app as most code is re-used. That being said, it looks like in this case the DataGrid simply does not meet your requirements. Cheers, and welcome to the GWT community!